# Parsing this message

Tags: java, regex, linux, parsing, programming-languages

So I am stuck with message of the form

```
{ Envelope={ Category1={ "key1"="value1"} Category2={ "key2"="value2", "key3"="value3"} } }
```

How do I even go about parsing this weird structure ? I am only interested in the  key-value pairs. I want all of them and I don't care about Categories. Ideally like this:

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
key3 = value3
```

(with or without quotes)

Solution in any language is acceptable. Perl, Python, Java, C, C++, GNU tools (sed,awk...). The only solution I can think of right now is to write a Java/C++ program but want to avoid that if there are simpler methods out there.

Comment: Use JSON parser in JavaScript, use map.entry in Java

Comment: @ShoaibChikate That's not quite JSON

Comment: Downvoters, please explain why you are downvoting. I am just looking for ideas. The amount of downvoting recently here is defeating the whole purpose of this site.

Comment: @chrylis exactly. AFAIK this weird structure is not parseable using standard libs/formats

Comment: @IanMcGrath I down-voted because I like to see some effort from the OP. So often these questions that are "looking for ideas" seems like they are actually hunting for a solution.

Comment: @chrylis little bit unclear about the input

Comment: @Duncan , fair enough. My question does look like that.

Comment: @IanMcGrath And the fact that this question was duly answered (and accepted) with a full working solution merely adds to my suspicions ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through bash tool `grep`,

```
$ grep -oE '"[^"]*"="[^"]*"' file
"key1"="value1"
"key2"="value2"
"key3"="value3"
```

From `grep --help`

```
-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
-E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
```

**Explanation:**

- `"` Matches a literal `"` symbol.
- `[^"]*` Matches any character but not of `"` zero or more times.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit too? I am rusty on RE.

Comment: explained. I think you figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

a Java Solution

`String regex = "\"(\\w+)\"=\"(\\w+)\"";`

Group 1 is the key

Group 2 is the value

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String w = "{ Envelope={ Category1={ \"key1\"=\"value1\"} Category2={ \"key2\"=\"value2\", \"key3\"=\"value3\"} } }";
    String regex = "\"(\\w+)\"=\"(\\w+)\"";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(w);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Value: " + m.group(2));   
    }
}
```

Output

```
Key: key1
Value: value1
Key: key2
Value: value2
Key: key3
Value: value3
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer inspired me to practise regular expressions. Regular expressions FTW.